# How can I expand the scope of a variable in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm writing a macOS Command Line Tool in Xcode. The variable "num1" keeps returning nil. I declared it in the beginning so it should be a global variable. How can I address this?

```
var num1: Int!

if userChoice == "add" {
    print("Enter first number")
    if let num1 = readLine() {
    }
}

print ("\(num1)")
```

Comment: That `let num1` introduces a second variable unrelated to the first and local to the `if`. You should give that one another name (and assign to the global once you got a proper input). Also make the global non-optional.

Comment: Also note that the 2nd `num1` variable will be an optional `String`, not an `Int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you have two `num1` variables. The 2nd one is scoped to just the block of the 2nd `if` statement.

You also have an issue that `readLine` returns an optional `String`, not an `Int`.

You probably want code more like this:

```
var num1: Int?

if userChoice == "add" {
    print("Enter first number")
    if let line = readLine() {
        num1 = Int(line)
    }
}

print ("\(num1)")
```

Of course you may now need to deal with `num1` being `nil`.

One option is to properly unwrap the value:

```
if let num = num1 {
    print("\(num)")
} else {
    print("num1 was nil")
}
```

Comment: Works much better! Only thing now is how can I output "Optional(11)" as just 11?

Comment: See my update. Sounds like you should be reading "The Swift Programming Language" book from Apple. It covers all of the important things like optional variables and the rest of the language.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the second num1 something else.
2. Put something in the if.

```
 var num1: Int!

 if userChoice == "add" {
    print("Enter first number")
    if let num2 = readLine() { 
        // This if-let runs if num2 is not nill. 
        print ("\(num2)")
        num1 = Int(num2)
    }
}

print ("\(num1)")
```

Comment: I'm having a strange sense of Déjà vu :)